# Regex to remove trailing optional garbage

Tags: regex

I want to clean strings that may contain garbage at the end, always separated by a forward slash / and if there is no garbage, there is no separator.

Example > expected output

```
Foo/Bar > Foo 
Foobar > Foobar
```

I tried several versions like this one to extract the payload only, none of the worked:

```
(.*)\/.*

(.*)?\/.*

(.*)?\/*.*
```

And so on. Problem is: i always only get the first or second line to match.

What would be the correct expression to extract the wanted information?

Comment: What is the expected result for `Foo/Bar > Foo Foobar > Foobar`

Comment: The payload and garbage always contains simple letters from the alphabet, no other chars. So I would expect Foo for your example.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: @The fourth bird - I'm using Python and re.search()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first and second pattern capture till before the first `/` so that will not give a match for the third line as there is no `/` present.

The third pattern matches the whole line as the `/*` matches an optional forward slash, so the capture group will match the whole line, and the `.*` will not match any characters any more as the capture group is already at the end of the line.

You could write the pattern with a capture group for 1 or more word characters as the first part, and an optional second part starting the match from `/` till the end of the string.

In the replacement you can use the first capture group.

```
^(\w+)(?:\/.*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word characters in group 1
- `(?:\/.*)?` Optionally match `/` and the rest of the line (to be removed after the replacement)
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ZCmtI/1).

There is no language listed, but an example using JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /^(\w+)(?:\/.*)?$/m;
const str = `Foo/Bar
Foobar`;
const result = str.replace(regex, "$1");
console.log(result);
```

---

Example using Python

```
import re

regex = r"^(\w+)(?:\/.*)?$"
test_str = ("Foo/Bar\n"
    "Foobar")
result = re.sub(regex, r'\1', test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
Foo
Foobar
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/lewkgW)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) here as:

```js
const cleanString = (str) => str.replace(/\/.*/, "");

console.log(cleanString("Foo/Bar"));
console.log(cleanString("Foobar"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This task doesn't need the power of regex, you need to split on the first slash, e.g. in Python:

```
test_string.split('/', 1)[0]
```

I think the reason your regex doesn't work is that `Foobar` has no `/` to match on. So for regex you need to handle none, one, or many slashes. Again, in Python:

```
>>> test = ['foobar', 'foo/bar', 'foo/bar/baz']
>>> for s in t:
    print(re.findall('^(.*?)(?=/|$)', s))
        
['foobar']
['foo']
['foo']
```

The regex says: from the start of the string, group all characters (non-greedy) until either a slash or the end of the string.

Comment: Sure, was my first attempt, too. But putting it into a comprehensive list, the regex approach looks cleaner.

Comment: Nevertheless - thank you. First time I see ?= in action!

Comment: Need to mention: I tested the first option, too: It's way faster than the pure regex solution: 10 Mio. words are cleaned in about 11 seconds using RegEx and around 8 seconds using the split method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing a regex.split on / and select the first element from the list. For example in python:

import regex as re

new_string = re.split('/',string)[0]

Comment: Thanks. That was my first attempt, too. But putting it into a comprehensive list, the regex approach looks cleaner.

Comment: Need to mention: I tested this option, too: It's way faster than the pure regex solution: 10 Mio. words are cleaned in about 11 seconds using RegEx and around 8 seconds using the split method.